# Interfacing ultrasonic range sensor (HCSR-04) with avr ATmega-32?

Tags: c, sensors, avr, atmega

I am using an ultrasonic range/sonar sensor (HCSR-04) with an AVR ATmega32A. I have written the code understanding the concept of how the sensor works but although the program compiles correctly the device doesn't give any result.

The LCD is showing "out of range" which means PINC1 isn't going high. Is my method for checking if a bit is high or low correct? Should I use the `bit_is_set(PORTC,PINC1)` function? I am using the default frequency 1 MHz. PINC0 is connected to trig and PINC1 is the echo input. Here is the code:

```
#include<avr/io.h>
#include<util/delay.h>
#include"lcd.h"

int main(void){
    ini_lcd();
    TCCR1B|=1<<CS10;
    DDRC|=1<<PINC0;
    int a=0,b=0;
    while(1){
        TCNT1=0;
        PORTC|=1<<PINC0;
        while(TCNT1<100);
        PORTC&=~(1<<PINC0);

        TCNT1=0;
        while(!(PORTC&(1<<PINC1))) && TCNT1<30000) ;  // checking if echo has become high  and not exceeding the time for max range i.e 5 m
        ///send_string("out");
        b=TCNT1;
        if(b<30000){
            TCNT1=0;
            while(PORTC&(1<<PINC1));    // waiting until the echo become low again
            a=TCNT1;
            go_to_pos(1,5);
            send_int(a/58);
        } else {
            go_to_pos(1,5);
            send_string("out of range");
        }
        _delay_ms(20);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The main problem I see in your code that is repeated a few times is how you're trying to read the input I/O line, for example:

```
while(PORTC&(1<<PINC1));    // waiting until the echo become low again
```

Should become:

```
while(PINC&(1<<PINC1));    // waiting until the echo become low again
```

The `PORT` registers are the output latches and will either contain the last value written to them or the power-on default value of zero. You need to use the `PIN` registers to read the current state of the I/O pin.

Comment: it works ,thanks.I wrote (PORTC&(1<<PINC1)) thinking it will be like while(UCSRA&(1<<UDRE)) ; i thought PINC1 bit is in PORTC register.But we also write DDRC|=1<<PINC1; so my intution says that my assumption is contradictory.As till now whether PINC or PINA is a bit or register didn't bother me much so i just skipped it.Would u like enlighten me about PIN register .

Comment: When the DDR register sets the pin as an input the PORT bits control whether the pull-ups are enabled so that's why they work differently that you might expect. There's a good little diagram / description here: http://www.avrbeginners.net/architecture/ioports/ioports.html

Answer (score 0):

you need to make the tick counts in TCNT1 = 300000 not 30000 when checking for the Echo pin, since your clock is 1000000 HZ then each 0.1us TCNT1 is incremented by 1 so for 300000 tick you get 30000 us (waiting time) which is equal to the time needed for the echo to travel back at 5 meter (max range for the HCSR04)